# How to fix the scope for gross sweat/respiration loss in c

Tags: c, scope, calculator

The program is supposed to add the fluid intake to the gross respiration loss, but it does not do that.  The problem is just before the second switch statement.  I have to initialize F1 to 0.0, or else the program won't compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
float W1;
printf("Prerun Weight (lbs): ");
scanf("%f", &W1);

float W2;
printf("Postrun Weight (lbs): ");
scanf("%f", &W2);

float NL = W1 - W2;
printf("Net Loss: %.2f lbs\n", NL);

char pitStop;
float P;
float S;
pitStop:
printf("Pit stops? (Y/N): ");
scanf(" %c", &pitStop);
switch (toupper(pitStop))
{
    case 'Y':
    printf("Ounces lost: ");
    scanf("%f", &P);
    S = NL - (P / 16);
    printf("Sweat/Respiration loss: %.2f lbs\n", S);
    break;
    case 'N':
    S = NL - 0;
    printf("Sweat/Respiration loss: %.2f lbs\n", S);
    break;
    default:
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    goto pitStop;
    break;
}
// problem is here
char fluidIntake;
float F1 = 0.0;
float G1 = (S * 16) + F1;
float G2 = ((S * 16) + F1) / 16;
fluidIntake:
printf("Fluid Intake? (Y/N): ");
scanf(" %c", &fluidIntake);
switch (toupper(fluidIntake))
{
    case 'Y':
    float F1 = 0.0;
    printf("Ounces drank: ");
    scanf("%f", &F1);
    G1 = (S * 16) + F1;
    float G2 = ((S * 16) + F1) / 16;
    printf("Gross sweat/respiration loss: %.2f oz\n", G1);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Gross sweat/respiration loss: %.2f lbs\n", G2);
    sleep(1);
    break;
    case 'N':
    float G1 = S * 16;
    float G2 = ((S * 16) + 0) / 16;
    printf("Gross sweat/respiration loss: %.2f oz\n", G1);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Gross sweat/respiration loss: %.2f lbs\n", G2);
    sleep(1);
    break;
    default:
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    goto fluidIntake;
    break;
}

float M;
printf("Minutes run: ");
scanf("%f", &M);
float H = M / 60;
sleep(1);
printf("Hours run: %.2f\n", H);

float DM;
sleep(1);
printf("Distance run (mi): ");
scanf("%f", &DM);
float DK = DM * 1.60934;
sleep(1);
printf("Distance run (km): %.2f\n", DK);

float SR1 = G1 / M;
sleep(1);
printf("Sweat rate 1: %.2f oz per min\n", SR1);
sleep(1);
float SR2 = G2 / H;
printf("Sweat rate 2: %.2f lb per hour\n", SR2);
sleep(1);
float SR3 = G1 / DK;
printf("Sweat rate 3: %.2f oz per km\n", SR3);
sleep(1);
float SR4 = G1 / DM;
printf("Sweat rate 4: %.2f oz per mi\n", SR4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that while defining G1 and G2, you already calculate them

```
float F1 = 0.0;
float G1 = (S * 16) + F1;
float G2 = ((S * 16) + F1) / 16;
```

which is useless and wrong. Just define the variables, wait until you read F1 and perform the calculations then. I've seen that odd pattern (defining formulas at the time variables are declared but before the terms' values are known) more than once lately, wondering why that is.

A worrying aspect of your program is not only that you use `goto` (which in my opinion should be used only if you have no other reasonable option), but that your goto jumps **out of the switch statement**. You should really rewrite that logic, it's asking for trouble.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I wasn't really sure what to do for that.  I am currently taking cs50 at Harvard online and the professor said that was a bad practice.  This is only going to be for my use only though, so unless I something happens, I think I will leave it.  If I were to make this on a website, is there anyway of doing that, or would I have to rewrite it in another language because C works in the command line.

Comment: @BillCarroll You should rewrite that using a control structure like `do ... while`, and I encourage you to think a bit how you could rewrite the code without goto, as having a good grasp of control structures is fundamental in programming.

Comment: Okay.  I know it says not to say this in the comments, but thank you.